# What is this plant? (it looks like arrow-wood or boldo)

Tags: identification

I've been using that app PlantNet but none of its suggestions really looks like my plant.
It is still young (about 1 or 2 months old).[image: unknown plant]

Comment: It looks like it has a square stem - is that correct?

Comment: Doesn't quite look like either, but it does look like a tree. Approximately where in the world are you?

Comment: The photo was taken in Sao Paulo - Brasil
and I don't think it's a square stem because the stalk is round like a cilinder.